Completeness of $X$ with normal distribution $N(\theta,\theta^2)$ with equal mean and standard deviation: Integral of scale of a function
Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a Borel function such that, for every $a > 0$, we always have:
$$\begin{equation*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(ax)\exp \left(-\frac{1}{2}(x-1)^2\right)dx =0
\end{equation*}$$
Does it follow that $f = 0$ almost surely ? Does the answer change if we limit the attention only to $f \in L^{\infty}$ ?
The background of the question is that, suppose $X$ obeys the distribution $N(\theta, \theta^2)$ for some $\theta> 0$ and we wish to determine if $X$ is a (boundly) completes statistic for $\theta$. Expanding the definition out with a change of variable will give the statement of the problem above. I am looking for an analysis solution .
Intuitively, the exponential centers at $1$ and the scale is not centered at $1$. A counterexample would be surprising but I cannot prove it.

Noting that the integral equation can be written as
$$\mathbb E \left (f(aZ+a)\right )=0, \, Z \sim \mathcal N(0,1),$$
a counterexample can be designed as follows:
$$\color{blue}{f(x)=\frac{\max(x,0)}{|x|\Phi(1)}+\frac{\min(x,0)}{|x|(1-\Phi(1))}=\begin{cases}
     \frac{1}{\Phi(1)} & x>0\\
    \frac{-1}{1-\Phi(1)} & x<0
    \end{cases}}$$
for $x\neq0$ where $$\Phi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp \left(-\frac{1}{2}x^2\right)\text{d}x$$ denotes the cdf of $Z$, and  $f(0)$ can be set to any number.

PS: From the section "Relation to sufficient statistics" in the Wikipedia page on complete statistics, it can be indirectly proven that there is no complete statistic for $\mathcal N(\theta,\theta^2)$.

This is so simple! Thank you. Your idea works. Your choice of constants actually does not work. But I will accept your answer.

@温泽海  You are welcome!  The first equation is correct. I just added a missing $-$ in the second equivalent equation for $x<0$.

@温泽海 you may also check my answer to the following related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4892966/1231520
